# MYSQL Stored Procedures on Adminer

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SPs and using Adminer

```
SET @startDate = initDate;
SET @startTime = initTime;
```

My stored proc begins like this but throws an error when there is more that one line. initDate and initTime are input vars

It looks like some sort of issue with the delimiter as if both assignments go on one line with a , separator the error shifts further in to the SP.

Error message 
Syntax error near 'SET @startTime = initTime' at line 4 13:32:48

Would appreciate any tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally when defining a stored procedure, you re-define the delimiter beforehand:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE . . .
BEGIN 
    SET @startDate = initDate;
    SET @startTime = initTime;
    . . .
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

It does sound like you might have a problem with the delimiter.  I also advise you to wrap the body in `BEGIN`/`END`.

Comment: Cool thanks Gordon.  Adminer does that in the background so might be best to work around Adminer for now -- that helps!