# Stored Procedure MySQL Syntax error in Adminer

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, adminer

I'm very new to stored procedures in MySQL in general.  I am trying to create one in Adminer and I keep getting a syntax error message:

```
Syntax error near '$$ CREATE PROCEDURE test() BEGIN SELECT * from lead; END$$ DELIMITER' at line 2
```

I'm trying to create a procedure named `test` to select all the records from a table.  The code I put into Adminer is as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
  SELECT * from lead;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

However, if use the MySQL CLI, and enter the exact same code line for line, it works

```
mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE test()
    -> BEGIN
    -> SELECT * from lead;
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
```

If I call the procedure test, I get all the records from the lead table.

I've logged into both Adminer and the CLI with the same credentials so I'm fairly confident it's not a permissions thing.  I know I am missing something; can any one assist with a point in the right direction?

Comment: Looks like Adminer doesn't understand `DELIMITER`. It probably uses something in the GUI in place of this.

Comment: But [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/adminer/bugs-and-features/258/) says it should work.

Comment: So does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44170935/mysql-stored-procedures-on-adminer

Comment: @Barmar - thanks...I've seen both those posts.  I've also removed the last `DELIMITER` line and made sure there wasn't a new line after the `$$`.  Still no joy.